# ubuntu software center can't open

Tags: software-center

When I was trying to update program and systme by Ubuntu softwar Center. Internet cut off and now I can not download any software to download Ubuntu Center and can not install  through Terminal? what can i do?

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

It may happen some files are corrupted. 
In this case I would try the standard remedy: sudo apt-get update
It helps in 75% of problems.